# Cannot scroll in modal on mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, modal-dialog

My website has a ajax interaction that brings up a full-bleed modal that is suppose to scroll scrolls.

- go to [www.morningharwood.com/works](http://www.morningharwood.com/works)
- Click on a project
- go into a project

*The Project modal will open up.*
Unfortunately scrolling will no work on touch.  To note the page scrolls just fine if you press and drag from the on the projects' hero image.

**Does anyone know what would prevent scrolling on mobile touch?**

Comment: I just tried to have a look, but for some reason every time I clicked a project it warped me into the nav menu. I'm on an iPhone 4S, iOS 5.

Comment: damn it my friend just told me this too.. arg I need to figure this wonkey thing out.  Thanks for trying.